# How to place 2 Input boxes on 1 line

Tags: html

Could I ask how I could place these input boxes and the Sumbit button on the same line please?

```
<td id="header-right">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class = "Login-Bar"><div style = "width: 200px;">
            <form action = "Login.php" method = "post">
               Username: <input type = "text" name "Username" size = "10"> 
               Password: <input type = "text" name "Password" size = "10"> 
               <input type = "Submit">
            </form></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
```

Thats the source code I have... It shows above my NavBar to the left, however I expected this to show on that same line, but it never it placed it as all under each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Don't use tables for layout](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm)
2. [use label tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)
3. Assign style `float: left` to both: labels and input fields. Then add clear below them (if you have any issues with elements overlapping each other).

Alternative would be to assign `display: inline` to the input fields.

Comment: @user1591117 Awesome :) glad I could help. Feel free to mark it as an answer ✓ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this style to the form:

```
form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px; /* or whatever width makes it work for you */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help also, I did this from the poster that posted the same time as you!. Thanks anyway thats exactly what I needed to do :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your css.

```
input {
   float: left;
}
```

If you want to add some spacing. You can do something like this

```
input {
       float: left;
       margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Great idea with the spacing!, I think I'll add that now! :D. Thanks for the help again!.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner table definition to something like:

```
<form action="Login.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="Login-Bar">
                Username:
                <input type="text" name "Username" size="10" /></td>
            <td class="Login-Bar">Password:
                <input type="text" name "Password" size="10" /></td>
            <td>
                    <input type="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VWw5f/).